# Count and group by Power BI

Tags: group-by, count, powerbi

I am beginner at Power BI and I'm trying to group my data by "Opp title" and count the number of rows of dates:

[image: Click here]

The result will be :

[image: Click here]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Step 1.  Select the table visual where your data is located in the Report Pane.

Step 2.  In the Visualizations Pane, right click on the date Value in the Values area (not Filters area) and select `Date` instead of `Date Hierarchy`.

Step 3.  In the Visualization Pane, right click on the date Value (same place) and instead of `Don't Summarize` select `Count`.

Comment: You are welcome.  Here are 2 good resources to study if you are beginning with Power Bi Desktop.  1)  There is a free video course at edx.org taught by the Microsoft people:  https://www.edx.org/course/analyzing-and-visualizing-data-with-power-bi .  2) There is a free PDF rookie to rockstar in power bi which teaches you good techniques:  http://radacad.com/online-book-power-bi-from-rookie-to-rockstar both might ask you to register or your email address, but the content is great for beginners.

Answer (score 6):

Select Advance editor on table and Select table -> Transfrom Tab -> select table and Group by option -> In Group by Select Advanced -> Select columns and mention the new column name -> give Ok button.[image]