# Count Row of Status in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, business-intelligence

i need help in Power Bi on how to count row of status (Critical,Reorder,Cutoff,Ideal,Overflow) as attached in Power BI?

[image]

Thank you so much.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535920/count-and-group-by-power-bi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this **calculated table**

```
Status Count = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'Table',
    'Table'[Status],
    "Count", COUNTROWS('Table')
)
```

With this sample data:

[image]

You'll get the following result:

[image]